# .htaccess issue for 5 variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Following is my `.htaccess` file.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

when i do

```
ehco "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
```

with 3 parameters, it shows me

```
Array
(
    [page] => test
    [s] => 1
    [o] => 9
    [p] => 
    [q] => 
)
```

but if more than 3 parameters, it says not found.
The `.htaccess` is working fine for the following URL
**myhost/mysite/page/s/o**
but not for 
**myhost/page/s/o/p**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some changes of your code:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: you mean to add these 3 lines below the 1st rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

Your correct full .htaccess can be this:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4&q=$5 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3&p=$4 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,20})/([^/]+)/?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```